# Are tathastu devatas(ashwini devatas) real? Will they fulfill everything we utter?

Tags: gods, goddess, words

It is said to me that tathastu devatas come around 5'O clock or sometime in the evening. At that time, we should speak only good and positive words because, those gods will make our wish come true.

So, what if our enemies wish some bad to happen to us at that time? Will they fulfill?

Are tathastu devatas real?

What I have seen on a video regarding this is

> What ever we wish for us/others, will become true to ourselves. That means if we pray for our wellbeing, it will happen. If we pray for others bad, the same will happen to us.

What about this?  - if we just utter in the flow of words like if we scold others normally in daily life like **idiot or stupid**.   (Sorry for using these words in this community, just to make you know what exactly I want to say.)

Comment: What is a *tathastu devata*? :)

Comment: Around 5'O clock in the morning?

Comment: Tathastu devata=Devatas who say "Tathastu (so be it)" when people ask something from them. @Vivikta

Comment: @Rickross , I already guessed that. So, which *devtaas* are there then, which don't say *tathastu* when granting boon.? Some another class of  ***A**tathastu devtaas* also there? :p

Comment: May be these are certain deities who come on earth at particular times and very easily grant wishes. @Vivikta

Comment: Vivikta and @rickross , I forgot to mention the word 'ashwini devatas'. Tathastu devatas are also called ashwini devatas. It is in the evening, might not be only at 5'O clock

Comment: Aswini Devatas are real. But whether they easily grant wishes like you've said is something that needs to be found. BTW I have also heard that during early morning and at around the evening Deities come to earth. @Learner